# How to use the Multi Region Access Point in AWS S3 using the hostname?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-s3-access-points

According to the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPointRequests.html) we should be able to use the Multi Region Access Point using the format `<mrap-alias>.accesspoint.s3-global.amazonaws.com` hostname but this doesn't seem to work for me.

I can access the access point using the ARN, but the hostname method gives me the error
`"An error occurred (NoSuchBucket) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The specified bucket does not exist".`

Is there some additional configuration that is required to enable this access using hostname? I have kept the "Block all public access" as Off for both the access point and the bucket as well.

Comment: Got it working. Got the solution here: https://repost.aws/questions/QUe6vKotBZQEKZsqPn8f6AxQ/how-to-use-the-multi-region-access-point-in-aws-s-3-using-the-hostname